# Using parameters as column to filter

Tags: optimization, oracle12c

as my title, I'm confused that whether should I re-write my code from static to DBMS. Here is my code

```
Declare
p_Int number;
p_SchoolId number;
p_Result varchar2;
v_Exist number;
BEGIN
    IF v_Exist = 0 THEN
        SELECT SUM(Students) INTO p_Result
        FROM SCHOOL sch 
        WHERE
            CASE
            WHEN p_SchoolId IS NULL THEN 1
            WHEN sch.SchoolId = p_SchoolId THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END = 1
        AND
            (
            CASE
            WHEN p_ClassId IS NULL THEN 1
            WHEN sch.classid <> p_ClassId THEN 1
            ELSE 0 END = 1
            )
        AND District IN ('NA','YB','NT') ;
    END IF;
END;
```

As I know, case when can't using Index, Recently, I have nearly 10.000 records but It can be reach to more than 10mil in the future.

My questions are: I use parameters as column to filter is good, does any way to make it better? And whether should I re-write from static to DBMS to ensure performance in the future(I won't create any Function-Based-Index).

I'm using Oracle-12c.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm wrong, you could get rid of `CASE` as follows:

```
SELECT SUM (Students)
  INTO p_Result
  FROM SCHOOL sch
 WHERE     (   sch.schoolid = p_schoolid
            OR p_schoolid IS NULL)
       AND (   sch.classid <> p_classid
            OR p_classid IS NULL)
       AND district IN ('NA', 'YB', 'NT');
```

See how it behaves, compare explain plans.

Comment: It's the same everything IN EP except cardinality(reduce)

Comment: Well, yes - when there's not that much data (and 10.000 rows is close to *nothing*, as far as Oracle is concerned), you probably won't notice any significant difference.

Comment: I tried create a table test  with 2mil records and It also nearly no change (cost reduce from 1348 to 1339)

Comment: Even better (if it is *fast* enough).